# How to trace Bouncing E-mails in Action mailer (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I am using Active mailer to sending Emails,

I want to trace the mail ids which are bounced when i am sending the mails to the user.

Please give your valuable comments guys.

Thanks in Advance.

*HIKKU

Comment: did you found any solution with out using any gems or third party api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good explanation in Recepie #70 http://www.pragprog.com/titles/fr_rr/rails-recipes

Also take a look at http://blog.gipoo.net/2010/5/26/handling-bounced-emails-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Tried to edit this to remove the second link which no longer works. My edit was rejected for some reason.

Comment: The first link also no longer works. Says it's for Rails 1.x and is out of print. Contains a link to the Rails 3.x edition, which it also says is out of print.

Comment: Downvoted as neither link provides information. I'd suggest updating the post and I'll upvote it back.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use unique From-addresses when sending emails.
For example when sending email to user with ID 666, use the from address no-reply-666@example.com.

Then setup a script that receives the replies. If the reply is a bounce pull out the msg-id or whatever you need from the mail and store it.

Detecting whether the reply was a bounce or an actual reply from a real user can be tricky, because not all MTAs format the bounce messages properly.

An alternative to Postmark could be [MadMimi](http://madmimi.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I recently switch to using the email service [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/), just so I could know about bounced emails better.  They have a [bounce api](http://developer.postmarkapp.com/bounces) and [support webhooks](http://developer.postmarkapp.com/bounces#bounce-hooks).  I never could figure out a way to get that information back to my app from the MTA I had running.  It is a [pay service](http://postmarkapp.com/#pricing) so it might not work for you, but it has been useful for my project.

Comment: I agree - Postmark makes it all very simple. The pricing is very reasonable considering the pain they remove.